# Android programming Beginner

Tags: java, android

I am a c++ developer .I like to develop an application in android.Is it possible to develop apps without knowing Java?

Comment: you can refer to this [link](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/java-tutorial/) as start up.

Answer (score 5):

You can always use Android NDK, in which you can use c/c++ http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html

However, "using native code does not result in an automatic performance increase, but always increases application complexity.", so I guess it's recommended to use Java.

Answer (score 3):

I think you shall not be able to develop an Android app without knowing Java, since all Android's applications are written using the Java programming language. Furthermore, what's the problem in learning a new language? Java is a renowned language, with a good supporting API, a vast documentation and a helpful programming community. It certainly won't be a waste of time. And in any case, acquiring new knowledge is always a good idea and knowing Java will definitely make your app better (better performance, better memory management, so on) :D

Hope it helps ^^

Answer (score 2):

Android uses Java... so, no it's not possible.

However moving from C++ to Java isn't hard, they are both object oriented.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Seems like a perfectly good answer to me

Answer (score 1):

Well, no, as you will develop your applications in Java. However, as you know C++, you will easily understand the code examples and quickly adopt the language. Provided that, you can develop for Android without knowing Java beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

It's good to know an object orientated programming language already when starting with Android development - but you definitely will have to get to know Java, its structure and basics.

So the answer is no

Comment: Have any  difference  between android java and Oracle's core java?

Comment: certain packages and classes from Java SE are not included in Android. so, you will not have access to "full" java. otherwise, there are no differences.

Comment: same language, different API's